# installing python3 additional to python 2.7 on rhel server

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

we have `rhel 7.6` servers with `python 2.7`

now we want additionally to `python 2.7` to install the `python 3.x`

so both python versions will be installed

the question is about the pip version

as I understand pip latest version for `python 2.7` is `20.2.3`

but in case we also install `python 3.x`

then how to know which pip version is relevant here ?

dose pip version support both python versions?

Comment: There would be 2 commands `pip` and `pip3` just like `python` and `python3`. Also to avoid  all this you can use pip like `python -m pip install package` or `python3 -m pip install package`

Comment: in that case - from which site you recommended to download the pip.tar.gz  for python3?  ( for python 2,x its - https://pypi.org/project/pip/20.2.3/#files )

Comment: If you install python3 pip will by default be installed. yum install python3 should do the job

Comment: can you provide the best approach to install python3 on rhel server?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-8-install-python-3-or-python-2-using-yum/ this is a good guide.

Comment: thx but this is relevant for rhel 8 , do you have something for rhel 7?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222870/discussion-between-jessica-and-venky).